# ASP.Net User control How to read the child node

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control defined like this

```
<%@ Control .....

<Test:MyCustomControl id="xxx" runat="server>
</Test:MyCustomControl>
```

I would like to use this control on a page like

```
<Tag:MyControl runat="server">
  <div>
    my html
  </div>
</Tag...
```

In my custom control codebehind I would like to read the inner html and set it to a property of Test:MyCustomcontrol

Currently I am getting an error saying that "...does not have property div"

How can I do this?

Note: For clarification the inner html can be an arbitrary html, so I need a way to read anything that user has typed in the page.

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a templated user control (although there are other ways of doing this): http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/36574bf6(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

you can expose the div(running on the server) as a property from your UserControl

on the usercontrol html:

```
<div id="dvSomething" runat="server"></div>
```

on ur usercontrol codebehind ".cs file":

```
public System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl TheDiv 
{
    get
    {
        return dvSomething;
    }
    set {
        dvSomething = value;
    }
}
```

on the page that contains the usercontrol:

```
WebUserControl11.TheDiv.InnerHtml = "addin something to div from page";
```

good luck

Comment: yes, it does work, I always try the code before posting on Stackoverflow or before telling someone their code don't work

Comment: I did not mean that, I have put <div> as an example but the control is supposed to be designed to read any arbitrary html within the contol. So instead of <div> it could be <a...><span>...</span></a>. I need a mechanism to read any valid html.

Comment: yeah, thanks for the clarification , I added another answer just in case this one is helpful for somebody else

Answer (score 0):

I will keep the other question open in case someone need a different solution:

I'm not sure about your requeriments like but here are two solutions, I hope this is what you want:

one adding control(you can add any by the way, not only textbox) and other pure html as per you described

```
TextBox txtAdd = new TextBox();
txtAdd.Style.Add("width", "200px");
WebUserControl11.Controls.Add(txtAdd);

TextBox txtRead = (TextBox)WebUserControl11.Controls[1];

((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)WebUserControl11.Controls[0]).InnerHtml = "<b>something</b>";
string currentHtml = ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)WebUserControl11.Controls[0]).InnerHtml;
```

of course, the index will change depending how many elements you have on your user control